# Call to undefined method Srmklive\PayPal\Services\PayPal::setExpressCheckout()

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

hi guys i have a laravel 8 project and membership system . now its simple i want to pass a price to to a function and send my user to paypal to pay the price . i am using this package and following this tutorials :

```
https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal
https://www.positronx.io/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel/
https://www.codecheef.org/article/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel
```

when i hit pay route i get this error :

```
Call to undefined method Srmklive\PayPal\Services\PayPal::setExpressCheckout()
```

i read on issues that for expres checkout use version 1 . now i have some questions .
1-because i am using laravel 8 is it fine to use version 1 of this package ?
2-i unfortunately dont know much a lot about paypal so as far as i know express checkout keeps user on your site to pay . so i am fine if i redirect user to paypal and call back to my site too . so what is the function to do that ? if note `setExpressCheckout()` .
currently this is my controlller  :

```
   public function handlePayment()
    {
        $product = [];
        $product['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => 'Nike Joyride 2',
                'price' => 112,
                'desc'  => 'Running shoes for Men',
                'qty' => 2
            ]
        ];

        $product['invoice_id'] = 1;
        $product['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$product['invoice_id']} Bill";
        $product['return_url'] = route('success.payment');
        $product['cancel_url'] = route('cancel.payment');
        $product['total'] = 224;

//        $paypalModule = new PayPal::setProvider;
       $paypalModule = new PayPalClient;

        $res = $paypalModule->c($product);
        $res = $paypalModule->setExpressCheckout($product, true);

        return redirect($res['paypal_link']);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in composer.json

```
srmklive/paypal: "~1.0"
```

Comment: is it fine to use version 1 of package because i am using laravel 8 ?

Comment: Yes @Farshad, it is fine. It will not break anything.